# Firestore database, query collection and check if document exists in Python

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-firestore

I have a program reading data from a Google firestore database.
The database contains info for different users, but I need to load only data for a specific user.
The data is organized in this way:

```
UsersInfo (Collection)
--- User01 (document)
------ UserID  (field)
------ field01 (field)
------ field02 (field)
--- User02 (document)
------ UserID  (field)
------ field01 (field)
------ field02 (field)
--- User03 (document)
------ UserID  (field)
------ field01 (field)
------ field02 (field)
```

each of the User documents contains an identifying ID.

I know I can find the right document in the collection by using:

```
user_doc_ref = db.collection(u'UsersInfo').where(u'UserID', u'==', user_ID).stream()
for x in user_doc_ref:
    user_doc = x
```

which is assuming there's only one user document satisfying the query.
But this works no matter if the document actually exists or not, and always returns the generator user_doc_ref. How can I verify if this document exists? If I iterate over the generator, I can't use it anymore afterwards.

EDIT:
I found a way to get around it, by using:

```
current_user_doc = None
current_user_document_ref = db.collection(u'UsersInfo').where(u'UserID', u'==', user_ID).stream()
for dummy in current_user_document_ref:
    current_user_document = dummy.id
if current_user_document is not None:
    print(f"\tUser found in remote document {current_user_document}")
    doc_ref = db.collection(u'UsersInfo').document(current_user_document).collection(u'whatever').stream()
```

so, I'm iterating over the generator, but saving the document if it exists, so I can use it later on. I was wondering if there's a more direct and pythonic way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (sorry my python is not perfect):

```
user_doc_ref = db.collection(u'UsersInfo').where(u'UserID', u'==', user_ID).stream()
documents = [d for d in user_doc_ref]

if len(documents):
    for document in documents:
        print(u'Not empty')
else:
    print(u'empty query')
```

A better way to structure your data would be to make the document id the userId

Your data structure would look like:

```
UsersInfo (Collection)
--- UserID (for User01) (document)
------ field01 (field)
------ field02 (field)
```

and then you fetch the data like this

```
doc_ref = db.collection(u'UsersInfo').document(user_ID)

doc = doc_ref.get()
if doc.exists:
    print(f'Document data: {doc.to_dict()}')
else:
    print(u'No such document!')
```

Comment: I tried something similar, but I'm getting the error: "AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'empty' ".
And yes, I agree that it would be easier to simply rename the documents according to the UserID, but they're generated by someone else's code, so I don't have control over that :(

Comment: Can you check the length property of user_doc_ref if it is greather than 0? `len(user_doc_ref )`. Okay, I understand why you can't use the second method.

Comment: Nope, I tried that as well, but I get "TypeError: object of type 'generator' has no len()".
Clearly, I could do something like creating a list out of the generator, but then it's always the same problem :)

Comment: Okay, I added this 2 lines `documents = [d for d in user_doc_ref] if len(documents):`. Check if the updated answer works.

Comment: Yes, your solution, as I mentioned, involves creating a list out of the generator. Works, but I still don't like the way Firestore returns the query result. There's probably a good reason that I'm missing. :)
Anyway, thanks for the help!

Comment: Glad I could help.